# c# WPF ComboBox Data doesnt show the right datas

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, combobox

so I used the following code in my windows forms project, everything worked fine. Now I want to use this code in my wpf project, but the second combobox (cbFahrzeugModell) shows the datas of another ComboBox Item, idk why.

So, to sum up:
2 Comboboxes (cbFahrzeugHersteller and cbFahrzeugModell).
If I Chose an item in cbFahrzeugHersteller, than cbFahrzeugModell should show the appropiate items in cbFahrzeugModell. It's showing items, but it's showing the datas for the wrong ItemIndex of cbFahrzeugHersteller.

```
       private void cbFahrzeugHersteller_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        cbFahrzeugModell.IsEnabled = true;
        cbFahrzeugModell.Items.Clear();
        cbFahrzeugModell.Text = "";

        try
        {
            connection.Open();

            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            string query = "SELECT DISTINCT Modell FROM Autos WHERE Hersteller = @FahrzeugHersteller;";
            command.CommandText = query;
            command.Parameters.Add("@FahrzeugHersteller", SqlDbType.Text);
            command.Parameters["@FahrzeugHersteller"].Value = cbFahrzeugHersteller.Text;
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                cbFahrzeugModell.Items.Add(reader["Modell"].ToString());
            }

            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `SelectionChanged` event, the `Text` property of the `ComboBox` will be the previous selection. Try casting `cbFahrzeugHersteller.SelectedValue` or `cbFahrzeugHersteller.SelectedItem`. `e.AddedItems[0]` is another option. I'm guessing that any of those will be a string, but since you don't say how `cbFahrzeugHersteller` it might be something else. If that's the case you'll need to set a breakpoint and figure out exactly what by examining those properties in the watch window.

If you try to translate Winforms code directly into WPF, you'll run into endless problems like this. The two frameworks differ in profound ways. If you plan to stick with WPF, you really should learn MVVM and approach WPF on its own terms. Trying to write Winforms code in WPF is a guaranteed way to make yourself miserable.

A measure of the importance of the `ComboBox.Text` property in WPF is that after five years of writing WPF professionally every day and answering questions on Stack Overflow, I was mildly surprised to find that `System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox` *had* a `Text` property.

Comment: Worked with cbFahrzeugHersteller.SelectedValue, THANK U!